# Setting Symfony2 form data outside of the form builder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I've created a choices element in my Symfony2 project:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('myChoices', 'choice', [
        'choices' => [
            'foo' => 'Option foo',
            'bar' => 'Option bar'
        ],
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true
    ]);
}
```

which I render in my Twig view:

```
{{ form_widget(myForm.myChoices) }}
```

... but how can I retain the selection between form posts? I've tried passing a `userSelection` array containing a string `foo`, but all choices remain unselected:

```
{{ form_widget(myForm.myChoices, { 'data': userSelection }) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the data in my controller, during form initialisation:

```
$myForm = $this->createForm(new myForm, [ 'myChoices' => [ 'foo' ]]);
```